# How to do scaling animation effect between fragments on Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to create an animation between two fragments on Android.

After clicking on the "menu" button, I want to scale[minimize] current fragment and move it to right corner of the second fragment like this:

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAIPC.jpg)

And after click on this minimized fragment, I want to maximize it again with reversed animation.

Is it generally possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several libraries available for viewpager animations like

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked links but I think that it is not exactly what I want... Could you send little more informations?